# Start with AngularJS or Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have questions about learning Angular , I will wish to educate myself on this framework , but I saw that Angular 2 was proposed beta version so I therefore ask the following questions :

do I have to train myself Angular AngularJS or 2 ?

there's a noticeable difference and Angular JS is it brought to disappear in favor of Angular 2 ?

Thank you .

Comment: It's not in beta version. It's in final version now. And yes, AngularJS will slowly disappear in favor of Angular 2.

Comment: Angular 2 is released, so why learning the old one?

Comment: There will be still a lot of jobs, where you should have AngularJS knowledge. They will not disappear, but it is possible that a lot of them try to migrate their apps to Angular 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answers . I just asked myself because I asked on another forum , people tell me Angular JS and other Angular 2 with the same arguments that Niels Steenbeek

Answer (score 7):

With so many developer already using Angular1, Why do we need Angular2?

- Angular2 is built for 'Speed', it has faster initial loads, faster changed detection, and improved rendering times
- Angular2 is 'Modern', it takes advantages of features provided in latest Javascript standards and beyond such as classes,  modules and
  decorators
- Angular2 has simplified API, it has pure built in directives to learn, simpler bindings
- Angular2 enhances our productivity, to improve our data day work flow

So my opinion is to start with Angular2 and it does not necessarily required Angular1 knowledge!

Comment: ok thank you for your clear answer !

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS will not disappear in favor of Angular 2.
AngularJS still gets fixes and smaller improvements to make the migration to Angular 2 easier.

Angular 2 has reached the final release and will periodically updated.

I recommend to learn Angular 2. It is more perfomant, has a better tooling and really a nice documentation at http://angular.io.